# is it possible to sort an array and just get the return of the placements NOT change the order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array of numbers

```
counter[7,3,9,5,1]
```

if i do `counter.sort()` it will change the array to

```
counter[1,3,5,7,9]
```

is it possible to sort an array and just get the return of the placements NOT CHANGE THE ORDER
something like this

```
sortedArrayByPlacment[3,1,4,2,0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the array, sort it, then turn it into an object (for quick lookup) and map the original array onto the object to identify the new indicies.

You'll also need to pass a comparator function; `.sort` without any arguments will sort lexicographically, resulting in, eg, 11 coming before 2, which almost certainly isn't desirable.

```js
const arr = [7,3,9,5,1];
const indexByNum = Object.fromEntries(
  [...arr]
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .map((num, i) => [num, i])
);
const indicies = arr.map(num => indexByNum[num]);
console.log(indicies);
```

I'm using `Object.fromEntries` to make the mapping less computationally complex, but you could do without it if you wanted:

```js
const arr = [7,3,9,5,1];
const sorted = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a - b);
const indicies = arr.map(num => sorted.indexOf(num));
console.log(indicies);
```

PS: These snippets work only if the values are unique in the array